# How to add a leading zero to a %m-%Y date?

Tags: r

My sample dataset

```
data = c("2-2021", "8-2020", "11-2020", "11-2020", "7-2021", "12-2020", 
         "2-2021", "5-2021", "11-2020", "11-2020")
```

I require to add a leading zero to the month where applies.

Running this will throw all NA's

```
as.Date(data,format="%m-%Y")
```

So the desired output becomes

```
c("02-2021", "08-2020", "11-2020", "11-2020", "07-2021", "12-2020", 
         "02-2021", "05-2021", "11-2020", "11-2020")
```

Answer (score 4):

We can use `truncated` with `myd` from `lubridate`

```
library(lubridate)
myd(data, truncated = 2)
```

-output

```
[1] "2021-02-01" "2020-08-01" "2020-11-01" "2020-11-01" "2021-07-01" "2020-12-01" "2021-02-01" "2021-05-01" "2020-11-01" "2020-11-01"
```

---

The NAs in `as.Date` is not related to leading zeros, but the absence of day as a Date requires day, month and year part i.e. if we append the day part, it works

```
as.Date(paste0('1-', data), format = '%d-%m-%Y')
 [1] "2021-02-01" "2020-08-01" "2020-11-01" "2020-11-01" "2021-07-01" "2020-12-01" "2021-02-01" "2021-05-01" "2020-11-01" "2020-11-01"
```

Comment: i would only require `%m` and `%Y`

Comment: @AndresMora Date requires day, so we can add a placeholder day i.e. 1

Comment: i agree with your approach but i require to not have the day as i need to run a pivot wider later so i get only months and years

Comment: @AndresMora then, you may use `as.yearmon` from `zoo` which can still return a yearmon object with year and month

Answer (score 3):

Base R:

```r
paste0(strrep("0", 7 - nchar(data)), data)
#  [1] "02-2021" "08-2020" "11-2020" "11-2020" "07-2021" "12-2020" "02-2021" "05-2021" "11-2020" "11-2020"
```

If you need it in `Date` class and this is just an interim step, then you could instead do

```r
as.Date(paste0("1-", data), format = "%d-%m-%Y")
#  [1] "2021-02-01" "2020-08-01" "2020-11-01" "2020-11-01" "2021-07-01" "2020-12-01" "2021-02-01" "2021-05-01" "2020-11-01" "2020-11-01"
```

(which does not care if the month has a leading 0 or not). (Looks like akrun beat me to this second step by a few seconds :-)

Answer (score 1):

This is also a way we colud do it:

1. create a datetime format with `parse_date_time` and format it to month and year. which will automatically add leading zeros:

```
library(lubridate)

format(parse_date_time(data, "my"), "%m-%Y")
```

```
 [1] "02-2021" "08-2020" "11-2020" "11-2020"
 [5] "07-2021" "12-2020" "02-2021" "05-2021"
 [9] "11-2020" "11-2020"
```